# calculating Modulus on Massive numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, big-numbers

In the case I have two numbers large enough to justify using scientific notation twice $A \times 10^{B \times 10^C}$ or $Ae+Be+C$ How would I calculate Modulo without taking the numbers or any part of them out of scientific notation?

Comment: eulers and chinese remainder theorem..  the usual.... The powers are large but the *are* powers of $10$ so just go ahead and do them.

Comment: Yes Euler's and chinese theorem including Carmichael's theorem (which is very powerful) can be used, but it should be really easy if you know the usuals

Comment: In the case it's a number like the above modulo something small like 43 what would I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mod of numbers with large exponents \[modular order reduction\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033639/mod-of-numbers-with-large-exponents-modular-order-reduction). If it doesn't, then add details to clarify your problem e.g. what moduli are you considering, what examples have you considered, are there more specific constraints on your problem? By adding details you help us help you with your specific question.

Comment: This does answer my question!
I'll write out the formula I have as an answer shortly.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thing is, powers are cycle under modular arithmetic.

Find out what power it takes for $10$ to cyclic through and take $B\times 10^C$ modulo that.  ANd to do that you might need know what power modulo that is cycle modulo that.

For example to figure $58\times 10^{97\times 10^{43}}\pmod {63}$ ... (something I made up out of the top of my head).  $10$ and $63$ are relatively prime.  $\phi(63)=\phi 7\phi 9=6*6=36$ so $10^{36} \equiv 1\pmod{63}$ and

$58\times 10^{97\times 10^{43}} \equiv (-5)\times 10^{97 \times 10^{43}\pmod {36}}\pmod {63}\equiv (-5)\times 10^{25 \times 10^{43}\pmod {36}}\pmod {63}$

Now to figure out $10^{43}\pmod {36}$ $10$ and $36$ are relatively prime so I'll have to use chinese remainder theorem.

$10^{43}=2^{43}5^{43} \equiv 0 \pmod 4$

And $10^{43} \equiv 1^{43}\equiv 1 \pmod 9$ so $10^{43} \equiv 28\pmod {36}$ and

$58\times 10^{97\times 10^{43}}\equiv (-5)\times 10^{25 \times 28\pmod {36}}\pmod {63}\equiv$

$(-5)\times 10^{-11\cdot -8\pmod{36}} \equiv $

$(-5)\times 10^{88 \pmod{36}} \equiv $

$(-5)\times 10^{16}\pmod{63}$.

Okay $10^{16}$ is still pretty large.  We can use CRT again.

$10^{16} \equiv 1 \pmod 9$ and $10^{16}\equiv 3^{16} \equiv (3^6)^2*3^4 \equiv 3^4 \equiv 9^2\equiv 2^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 7$ so $10^{16}\equiv 46 \pmod {63}$

So $(-5)\times 10^{16}\equiv -5*46\equiv -5\cdot (-17)\equiv 83\equiv 21 \pmod {63}$.